# Edittext jumps to next edittext, but wrong

Tags: android, android-layout

I need help with my app. This is my xml file with Relative layout, and I need to jump to the next edittext after pressing Enter key. 
But there is a problem, if I'm writing to the editTextKm and press Enter key, it jumps to the editTextFullTank, but I need to jump to the editTextManufactYear. How to do it?

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSPZ"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextKm"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"            
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSPZ"
        android:inputType="number" 
        android:maxLength="7"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextManufactYear"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextKm"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextKm"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextKm"           
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextFullTank"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"            
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextKm"
        android:inputType="number" 
        android:maxLength="3"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextReserveTank"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextManufactYear"            
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextFullTank"            
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3" />        

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextFullTank"            
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:singleLine="false"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

For further details you can consult [Anddroid Developer blog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Focus movement is based on an algorithm which finds the nearest neighbor in a given direction. In rare cases, the default algorithm may not match the intended behavior of the developer. In these situations, you can provide explicit overrides by using these XML attributes in the layout file:

```
                    android:nextFocusLeft="reference"
                    android:nextFocusRight="reference"
                    android:nextFocusUp="reference"
                    android:nextFocusDown="reference"
```

Answer (score 1):

add the attributes:

`android:nextFocusDown="@id/your_next_edit_text_to_focus"` to each `EditText` according to what you need.

You can also use :

```
android:nextFocusUp="@id/your_next_edit_text_to_focus"
android:nextFocusLeft="@id/your_next_edit_text_to_focus"
android:nextFocusRight="@id/your_next_edit_text_to_focus"
```